# replace extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests for annotation?

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit

I have test

```
public class CandidateServiceTest extends
        AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests
```

But any my tests has common part and I want create abstract class for it.

In java I cannot extends from two or more classes.

can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build a small class hierarchy.  Create a custom abstract class that extends `Spring`'s `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` class, then have `CandidateServiceTest` extend that class.

```
public abstract class MyAbstractTransactionalJunit4SpringContextTests 
     extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests{
   //Custom logic, this class has super class AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests
}

public class CandidateServiceTest 
    extends MyAbstractTransactionalJunit4SpringContextTests{
    //Custom logic, this class has super class MyAbstractTransactionalJunit4SpringContextTests
}
```